# woocommerce cart with multiple subtotals from same products with multiple prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I am trying to make a store that the products have multiple prices, one for every supplier. And when i choose the products , show in the cart the prices and subtotals of each supplier. For example, i enter the store, then choose sugar and milk without knowing the prices, proceed to cart and in the cart page i can see: Sugar- Store 1 $10- Store 2 $20 / Milk - Store 1 $20 - Store 2 $30---Subtotal Store 1=$30 Store 2=$50. And that's it, i dont need to proceed with checkout, it's only to compare stores prices from equal products. i try variable products, i get to show the prices on cart but i can't make more than one subtotal array by the variable id. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
well, maybe this answer will help someone else in the future, i figure it out, i leave the function here just in case

   

 // Muestra los custom fields en el carrito
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'super_custom_field', 10, 2 );
function super_custom_field( $cart_data, $cart_item ) 
{
    $items_super = array();

    if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
        $custom_items = $cart_data;

    // Los busca desde el id
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    
    $supermercado_1 = get_field('super_1',7);
    $supermercado_2 = get_field('super_2',7);   
    $supermercado_3 = get_field('super_3',7);       

    if( $precio_1 = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'precio_1', true ))
    if( $precio_2 = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'precio_2', true ))
    if( $precio_3 = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'precio_3', true ))  
        
        $items_super[] = array(
            'name'      => __( 'Precios en supermercados', 'woocommerce'),
            'display'   => '<div>
                            <p class="super1 supermercados"><strong>' . ($supermercado_1). '</strong> <span>$' . ($precio_1). '</span></p>
                            <p class="super2 supermercados"><strong>' . ($supermercado_2). '</strong> <span>$' . ($precio_2). '</span></p>
                            <p class="super3 supermercados"><strong>' . ($supermercado_3). '</strong> <span>$' . ($precio_3). '</span></p>
                            </div>',

        );

    return $items_super;
}

//Suma los custom field de precio 1
//Elige el lugar donde lo muestra
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents', 'suma_precio_1', 10, 2 );
//este es despues del carro antes del checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'suma_precio_1', 20 );
//este es en el checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'suma_precio_1', 20 );


function suma_precio_1() {
    $total_1 = 0;

    $supermercado_1 = get_field('super_1',7);

    // Busca en el loop del carro el cutom field en cada producto y los suma y multiplica por la cantidad
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $precio_super_1 = (float) get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'precio_1', true );
        $total_1  += $precio_super_1 * $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
    if( $total_1 > 0 ){

        // The Output
        echo ' <tr class="super1">
            <td colspan="5"><p><strong>' .$supermercado_1.  '</strong></td> <td colspan="" style="text-align:right;"><span>$' . number_format($total_1, 2) . '</span></p></td>
        </tr>';
    }
}


//Suma los custom field de precio 1
//Elige el lugar donde lo muestra
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents', 'suma_precio_2', 10, 2 );
//este es despues del carro antes del checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'suma_precio_2', 20 );
//este es en el checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'suma_precio_2', 20 );


function suma_precio_2() {
    $total_2 = 0;

    $supermercado_2 = get_field('super_2', 7);

    // Busca en el loop del carro el cutom field en cada producto y los suma y multiplica por la cantidad
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $precio_super_2 = (float) get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'precio_2', true );
        $total_2  += $precio_super_2 * $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
    if( $total_2 > 0 ){

        // The Output
        echo ' <tr class="super2">
            <td colspan="5"><p><strong>' .$supermercado_2.  '</strong></td> <td colspan="" style="text-align:right;"><span>$' . number_format($total_2, 2) . '</span></p></td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
//Suma los custom field de precio 1
//Elige el lugar donde lo muestra
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents', 'suma_precio_3', 10, 2 );
//este es despues del carro antes del checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'suma_precio_3', 20 );
//este es en el checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'suma_precio_3', 20 );


function suma_precio_3() {
    $total_3 = 0;

    $supermercado_3 = get_field('super_3', 7);

    // Busca en el loop del carro el custom field en cada producto y los suma y multiplica por la cantidad
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $precio_super_3 = (float) get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'precio_3', true );
        $total_3  += $precio_super_3 * $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
    if( $total_3 > 0 ){

        // The Output
        echo ' <tr class="super3">
            <td colspan="5"><p><strong>' .$supermercado_3.  '</strong></td> <td colspan="" style="text-align:right;"><span>$' . number_format($total_3, 2) . '</span></p></td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```